# Gson, parse Json Array without wrapper

Tags: android, json, gson

I have this response:

```
[{ "age" : "12",
    "name" : "name1"

  },
  { "age" : "21",
    "name" : "name2"

  }]
```

How can i parse this response using Gson

```
ArrayList<PersonModel> persons = gson.fromJson(response, PersonModel.class);
```

this will not work with me

Comment: could you add your PersonModel and which error you get?

Comment: ArrayList<PersonModel> persons = gson.fromJson(response, PersonModel.class);  IDE don't let me do it like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're trying to convert your JSON array to an ArrayList of PersonModel (I'm assuming you already figured out how to write the PersonModel.class), you should use [TypeToken](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.7/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) to convert the JSON response to ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<PersonModel> persons = gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<List<PersonModel>>(){}.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to parse this is to use PersonModel[] instead. first make a model class like this:

```
public class MyModel {

public PersonModel[] persons;

}
```

then use it like below:

```
MyModel obj = gson.fromJson(response, MyModel.class)
```

Comment: I have used the answer above , your solution could work also . thank you

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working. I just tested.

ArrayList persons = gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken>(){}.getType());

Following solution doesn't work.

the easiest way to parse this is to use PersonModel[] instead. first make a model class like this:

public class MyModel {

public PersonModel[] persons;

} 
then use it like below:

MyModel obj = gson.fromJson(response, MyModel.class)